# Magento2 Add to cart button in row with grouped products

Tags: magento2, addtocart, grouped-products

In magento2 i want to add "Add to cart" button with qty for every single product of Grouped Product.
Is it possible? How?

I see that the form is only one.

I also need to remove the standard "Add to cart" button after the form.
See below attachment.

[image]

Comment: Yes: Here are some solutions to the same issue:
[How to add grouped products individually](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270767/how-to-add-group-product-into-the-cart-individually)

Answer (score 0):

I already did this on my project

app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
</page>
```

app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col sku" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?></th>
            <th class="col name" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <th class="col price" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="col button" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to cart') ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
            <tbody>
        <?php
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_item */
            foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item):
         ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>" class="col sku">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></strong>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col name">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="addtocart_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>">
                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

                            <input type="number" <?php if (!$_item->isSaleable()) : ?>disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?>
                                name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->isSaleable() ? 1 : 0 ?>"
                                title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                                class="input-text qty"
                                step="1" min="0"
                                data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                                data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>" class="col price">
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to cart')) ?>" class="col button">
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                        <button type="submit"
                                title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>"
                                class="action primary tocart"
                                form="addtocart_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                        </button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```