# How to add group product into the cart individually?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, catalog, grouped-products, associate-products

I have two simple products associated with a group product at the product description page and have a separate add to cart button with each product   I want to add these products to the cart individually But I am unable to When I press the first product to add to cart button both products are added to the cart. You can check the scenario by the following this [link](https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/antiparasitika-gia-skulia/ampoules/ampoules-skulou-antiphlebotome-spot-on.html)

```
this is my **group.phtml** file

   <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $grouped = $_product->load($_product->getId()); ?>                    
<?php $associatedProducts = $grouped->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($grouped); ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                         <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>

   <button title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart" onclick="window.forms.product_addtocart_form_6749.submit()">
   Add to Cart
</button>

 </form>
 <form action="https://magento2.petpanic.gr/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9tYWdlbnRvMi5wZXRwYW5pYy5nci9za3Vsb2kvYW50aXBhcmFzaXRpa2EtZ2lhLXNrdWxpYS9hbXBvdWxlcy9hbXBvdWxlcy1za3Vsb3UtYW50aXBobGVib3RvbWUtc3BvdC1vbi5odG1s/product/6749/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_6749" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="6749">
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="WZFyhGEmonXLbFmp">   
</form>

                   <!--button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php //echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>' + 'qty/' + $(this).previous().value)">Add to cart</button-->
                   </div>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="addtocart">
                <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_item);
?>
                    <?php /*
                      <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart">
           Add to Cart
        </button>

 </form> */ ?>
</td>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

I am currently new in Magento, also I tried many solutions but nothing gonna work for me. If there is any solution for this please let me know!
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code. It should work.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $grouped = $_product->load($_product->getId()); ?>                    
<?php $associatedProducts = $grouped->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($grouped); ?>

</form>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                            <div class="control qty">
                                <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
                                    <input type="number"
                                       name="qty"
                                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                                       class="input-text qty required"
                                       />

                                    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

                                    <!--
                                    <input type="number"
                                       name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                       data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                                       class="input-text qty"
                                       data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                                       data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                                    -->
                                    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="addtocart">Add to Cart</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="addtocart">
                    </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="unavailable"
                        colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>

<form>
```

Please note that this code will not add group product to cart, only simple product associated with group will be added as per your theme.

Comment: Did not work. :(

Comment: Ohh strange. I just checked it in your website creating the same form in inspect element and it worked for me actually. Your simple product added for me to cart.

Comment: Don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you please share the code you applied ? The exact one ? After my suggested changes ?

Comment: Actually @yash second add to cart button worked properly but first one creating the problem.

Comment: Alright, there might be something little issue, Please update your exact code after you implement my suggested edit, so that i can look at it and help you find out whats wrong.

Comment: I cannot see my suggested edit in your live link https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/antiparasitika-gia-skulia/ampoules/ampoules-skulou-antiphlebotome-spot-on.html

Comment: Check the question with your code

Comment: because I revert it wait I will apply your code

Comment: Check now please

Comment: I see. Actually you have generated form in wrong way. The main group product form is not actually rendering from your phtml file. So any form created in your file wont work. The second is working because you have ended form tag and created your one actually with static product id. What is the location of group.phtml file ?

Comment: What would be the solution? Because I am stuck at this point since 3day's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92644/discussion-between-yash-shah-and-shweta-mudgil).

Comment: Thank you so much It's worked for me!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good weekend.

Comment: @YashShah Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/350111/77631

Answer (score 1):

As far I Understood by looking at your shared link, you have set the default quantity of the simple products to `1` of Group product. In that case when user click on `Add to cart` button it will automatically add all simple product products of grouped product. First you need to set it to `0`. So it will add only those simple products which has quantity greater than `0` when user click on the `Add to Cart button`. For Reference please see the screenshot

[image]

It is not possible or I would rather say against the nature of magento to add simple products of grouped product in `isolation`. if you want to treat simple product individually why you made a part of these product as a grouped product then there is no meaning of grouped product.

Or if you really want to do that, replace my code with your one

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                           data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                </div>
 <button type="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>' + 'qty/' + jQuery(this).prev().children().val()">Add to cart</button>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
            && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
            && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $_item,
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
            ))): ?>
            <tr class="row-tier-price">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                        $_item,
                        \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                    ) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**I hope you got my point and it will help**

Comment: Half work is done by the previous developer! That's why I am getting the problem 
If you check the link below addtocart working fine as it adds only one product 
But I am unable to do this with the first product

Comment: I checked, it will add both simple products to cart that's same thing I wrote on my answer. if  you want to add him separately you don't need to add multiple add to cart button against each product. single button would done a job because it's a grouped product you just need to define other product quantity to `0` which you don't want to add it to cart.

Comment: So according to you, there is no way to add them individually with individually add to cart button?

Comment: Yes because it is against the nature of Magento grouped product working flow. logically if it is possible then why these products are the part of grouped product and why not it will show as a individual simple product. For Reference check magento documentation: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-grouped.html

Comment: last question why I am able to add them here individually https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/xira-trofi-skulon/acana-xira-trofi-skulon.html

Comment: The only way to neglect or avoid any simple product of grouped product from adding it to cart is by setting that simple product quantity to `0`. So it will not add in to cart and other simple products having quatity greater than `0` will added in to cart.

Comment: I checked your link. Don't go for `flash success message` of product addition. check the cart it added all products though I click only one simple product add to cart button

Comment: Have you check the listing page that I shared with you it adds only one product when I pressed one plus button https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/xira-trofi-skulon/acana-xira-trofi-skulon.html this link first product.

Comment: I checked the product detail page of your link

Comment: Not talking about product details page I am talking about product listing page why here added only one https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/xira-trofi-skulon/acana-xira-trofi-skulon.html

Comment: Yes It added single product because it will show simple products separately just like normal simple product. In order to verify, You just install a fresh magento and made a grouped product it will show as a single product in listing and show the lowest price of their simple products. It is not default nature of grouped product showing in listing. So I take it as you guys customizes the listing page show all simple products of grouped product instead of grouped product it self

Comment: How can I achieve this in the description page without maintaining default quantity zero here is the solution but I did not understand
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/add-to-cart-button-next-to-each-grouped-item

Comment: If you really want to follow this, though I don't prefer it then check my updated answer. What it does it actually use the `onclick` functionality on button. Just the request the url by passing associated item to `getAddToCartUrl` and quantity. It will add item separately just like a simple individual product.

Comment: First revert your changes completely then paste my code in your file `grouped.phtml`. Make sure you only copy paste foreach associated items code.

Comment: Now not even a single add to cart is working you can check https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/xira-trofi-skulon/acana-xira-trofi-skulon.html

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Not working Yet It's redirecting shopping cart page without adding any product! you can check here https://magento2.petpanic.gr/skuloi/xira-trofi-skulon/acana-xira-trofi-skulon.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92642/discussion-between-shweta-mudgil-and-muhammad-hasham).

Comment: @MuhammadHasham Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/350111/77631

Comment: @AnkitaPatel please check my answer against your above mentioned question I hope it will help you